# Terminate Javascript Loop From Click

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript script I'm developing for a phonegap app that gets device location until a certain target accuracy is obtained. If the target isn't met the script calls itself again into eternity. Usually it takes between 1-8 attempts depending on location and the last time used and then everything works fine. The problem I'm having is that some devices never reach that threshold (which is fine for the app), but ruins battery life because this script keeps running in the background. So how can I kill this script with a click event (the submit button)? I was thinking about setting a global var that hitting the submit button changes. Something like:

```
if (var != 'quit') {
    //function 
} else {
    ///nothing
}

function getlocation(position) {
    document.getElementById("lat").value = (position.coords.latitude);
    document.getElementById("long").value = (position.coords.longitude);
    document.getElementById("accu").value = (position.coords.accuracy);
    var accuracy = parseInt(position.coords.accuracy, 10);
    if (accuracy <= 50) {
        $('#scanner').removeClass('littlered').addClass('littlegreen');
    } else {
        setTimeout(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getDroplocation, onError, {
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        }), 3000);
    }
}
```

This hasn't been working though. I set the global var but nothing happens. Any better methods or ways of getting my aforementioned idea going? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [clearTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout) method clears a timer set with the setTimeout() method.

```
var to;

function getlocation(position) {
    document.getElementById("lat").value = (position.coords.latitude);
    document.getElementById("long").value = (position.coords.longitude);
    document.getElementById("accu").value = (position.coords.accuracy);
    var accuracy = parseInt(position.coords.accuracy, 10);
    if (accuracy <= 50) {
        $('#scanner').removeClass('littlered').addClass('littlegreen');
    } else {
        to = setTimeout(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getDroplocation, onError, {
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        }), 3000);
    }
}

//Add click event handler to a button to stop the looping
var button = document.getElementById("testbtn");
testbtn.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(to);
}
```

Comment: How do I add it back afterwards? I need this script to be usable again a few minutes later.

Comment: call the function that will execute the setTimeout() method again

Comment: no, that won't do, cause 'to' only stores the timeout id, manually call the getlocation function again should do

Comment: I see now. to is set in the function. makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

You want [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout)

Change

```
function getlocation(position) {
```

To

```
var tId;
function getlocation(position) {
```

and `setTimeout` to `tId=setTimeout`

And do a `clearTimeout(tId);` onclick of whatever you want to click or add a counter and kill after 10 attempts or so

for example

```
<input type="button" id="togglebutton" value="Stop" />
```

using

```
var tId,startPosition="whateverdefaultpositionissetto";
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("togglebutton").onclick = function() {
    if (tId) {
      clearTimeout(tId);
      this.value="Start";
    }
    else {
      getlocation(startPosition); 
      this.value="Stop";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do I add it back afterwards? I need this script to be usable again a few minutes later. What else do I put on the on click?

Comment: Nothing. Too bad I could not easily post more code from my iPhone since the accepted answer is identical but later than mine